Do you know how to make the outer area of ​the item invisible when dragging in React-beautiful-dnd?
I have a modal. Inside the modal there is a div2 consisting of div1 and dnd. When you drag an item from div2 towards div1, the item should not be visible. It should appear as if the item's zIndex is 0. Do you know these methods?
When I set the position to sticky or relative when the style is set to isDragging, the item was hidden when I dragged it to the outside area and succeeded, but when I dragged it down, it stopped at that position when scrolling down due to the position. Is there any way to solve this?
 ...provided.draggableProps.style,
 position: snapshot.isDragging ? 'sticky' : provided.draggableProps.style.position

